# Need to list all the item present in database in tool tip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

I have two models:

1. Book
2. Subject

One Book belongs to one Subject and one Subject has many Books, I have an index page for Subject which displays all the Subject names.

> index.html.erb

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>

<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_subjects_path, method: :delete do %>
  <table class="pretty">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Subject name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>

    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "subject_ids[]", subject.id %></td>
        <td><%= subject.try(:user).try(:username)%></td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<%=subject.books%>"><%= subject.name %></td>
        <td><%= subject.description %></td>
        <td><%= subject.active %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', subject_path(subject) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_subject_path(subject) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<%end%>
```

Now I need to display all the books belonging to the Subject when hovering on the name of the Subject(tooltip). I tried doing that and got active record collections(`<Book:ActiveRecords_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fedfgs>`) but I don't know how to iterate and display the names of all the Books in the tooltip when hovering over the Subject's name. Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: 'I tried doing that and getting active record collection' <-- can you elaborate on exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: just do <%= subject.books.map(&:name).join(', ')%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `subject.books` will give you an object of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. You just need to have the name of all the books, which you can do by writing:

```
<%= subject.books.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= subject.books.map(&:name).join(", ") %> # or whatever attribute to display name of the book
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `pluck` instead.

```
<%= subject.books.pluck(:name).join(', ') %>
```

Also it would be nice to have some reasonable `limit` set to it. Maybe 5 ?